# How to verify if in Singularity|Apptainer container?

Tags: singularity-container

According to the [shell doc](https://apptainer.org/docs/user/main/quick_start.html#shell):

> The change in prompt indicates that you have entered the container (though you should not rely on that to determine whether you are in container or not).

So other than the change in prompt, how **should** one determine whether they are in a container or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few environment variables you can check for:

- `SINGULARITY_BIND` - may still be empty if no binds/mounts are set
- `SINGULARITY_COMMAND` - *e.g.,* `exec`, `shell`, etc.
- `SINGULARITY_CONTAINER` - path to the image on the host OS
- `SINGULARITY_ENVIRONMENT` - usually `/.singularity.d/env/91-environment.sh` or something similar
- `SINGULARITY_NAME` - filename of the singularity image

Alternatively, checking for the existence of `/.singularity.d/Singularity`. If inside a singularity container, that is a copy of the Singularity definition used when creating the image. In general, it is really unlikely for `/.singularity.d` to exist on a normal host OS unless someone did something really weird.

Comment: A lot of possibilities there, but in the example container I just entered, there were no binds/mounts set, so `SINGULARITY_BIND` existed, but was empty like you mentioned. `SINGULARITY_COMMAND` did not exist and I'm not quite sure of a good way to test if `exec` or `shell` exist as `whereis exec` returns `exec:`. I suppose anyone could potentially make any of these env vars in the host system for unknown reasons (though it is unlikely they all would exist). Are you aware of any maintained test/script that would go through some logical checks using all/some of these?

Comment: The value of `SINGULARITY_COMMAND` isn't an actual binary or such, it's the specific keyword that was used when singularity was run: `singularity exec ...`, `singularity shell ...`, etc. No scripts that I'm aware of, but checking for `/.singularity.d` is probably the most simple/robust, as it requires root privs to modify `/`.

Comment: I would check the `\etc\os-release` if the OSes are different.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by passing the --cleanenv argument in the singularity shell command and checking if the PATH variable is the same as your host user's PATH:

```
#add an arbitrary file location to your PATH variable and check that it is present for the host
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/foo/bar
echo $PATH

#now pull up a shell in your container with --cleanenv to ignore the environmental variables of the host - such as the PATH we just exported
singularity shell --cleanenv yourimage.sif
#check that /path/to/foo/bar is not in PATH in your container
echo $PATH
```